# How can I define a section-like command?

Tags: sectioning

I would like to define a `\case` command that acts like a section, meaning that when I type `\case{Some Case}`, it will:

1. End the current paragraph if there is one
2. Write `\textsc{Some Case}`
3. End the line and leave some space after it
4. Make sure that the next paragraph won't be indented, even if I leave a blank line between the command and the paragraph

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Should it be numbered?

Comment: Thanks! No, it doesn't have to be numbered.

Comment: Well, use `titlesec`  to format, say `\paragraph` (the level under `\subsection`, not the paragraph in the usual sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\makeatletter
\newcommand\case%
{\@startsection {section}{2}{\z@}%
{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\scshape}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4] % dummy text 
\case*{A case} 
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{document}
```

Note: The version without the asterisk will be numbered, but using the same counter that `\section{}` (so do not use both in the same document). But that can be solved using a new counter and some other trick. More complex but the cases can be showed in the index:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{case}
\newcommand\case%
{\@startsection%
{case}%
{2}
{\z@}%
{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\scshape}}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2em}}% for toc
\newcommand*\l@case{\@dottedtocline{1}{3em}{1em}}% for toc
\newcommand{\casemark}[1]{}% for page headers
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}   \lipsum[1][1-4] 
\case*{A case}      \lipsum[2][1-4]
\case{Numbered case}        \lipsum[3][1-4]
\case{Another numbered case}        \lipsum[4][1-4]
\section{Bah}   \lipsum[1][1-4] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this suit what you need?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{noindentafter}
\newcommand{\case}[1]{%
  \par\textsc{#1}\NoIndentAfterThis}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\case{Jahyah}

Pellentesque hendrerit volutpat feugiat. Ut purus leo,
pulvinar sit amet vehicula non, pulvinar eu lacus.
Curabitur id mollisligula.
\end{document}
```

[image]